# Sabre Web Services consumption

Tags: sabre

What are the sabre web services/workflows needs to be utilized for searching, booking of flight seats using SOAP in asp .net.

Does bargain finder max helps in searching flight availability and booking of flight seat

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the existing Sabre API Workflow documentation? Should be a good starting point.

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/workflows/

Answer (score 0):

Workflow in airfare is simple. Shop, Book, Issue. These are separate items.

BFM does a search for available flights and fares. This is Shop.

Book is really just confirming the flight and putting a name on them. So this would probably be CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ

Reserving a seat must take place after a PNR has been created, but may take place before ticket is issued. But also may take place after.

Also, "jmacagno" is right. You should follow that link. I am only adding because as a travel agent, I have found that many people don't understand the workflow process in airfare.